# Can negative beta-decay emissons be used to create a cathode ray?

Tags: particle-physics

Specifically; would it be possible to use a sample of Strontium-90 to create a cathode ray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cathode rays are electrons, as are beta particles, so in that sense it's the same thing. However, from a discharge cathode, you get a huge number (aka a current) of electrons at small energies, typically electronvolts. Beta decay electrons start out with hundreds of kiloelectronvolts. To get them in number typical of cathode rays, you would need an insanely radioactive source... not a healthy approach.